# Travis-CI and .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, travis-ci, .net-4.6

I have a sample class library written on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 - used C# 6.0. So I want to setup my github repository with http://travis-ci.org/. Using Target framework .NET 4.6. I receive the following error in the [build log](https://travis-ci.org/M-Yankov/SWapi-CSharp/builds/132551655).

> TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.6' not supported by this toolset (ToolsVersion: 4.0).
>   System.ValueType' is not defined or imported 
>   CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Attribute` is not defined or imported
>   CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Int32` is not defined or imported 
>   CSC: error CS0518: The predefined type `System.UInt32` is not defined or imported
>   ...

After adding a target framework version to 4.5 build status is failed [link Build #5](https://travis-ci.org/M-Yankov/SWapi-CSharp/builds/132936973)

Is there any way to run it with .NET 4.6 ?

My `.travis.yml.` is :

```
language: csharp
solution: SWapi-CSharp.sln
install:
  - nuget restore SWapi-CSharp.sln
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release SWapi-CSharp.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5"
```

Comment: Mono xbuild only supports 4.5 so far. You have to downgrade or switch to AppVoyer.

Comment: ;( oh well. Maybe the another solution is to set `TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5"` in the .travis.yml and also rewrite my tests using `NUnit` instead of `Microsft.VisualStuido.UnitTests`. The last is not supported in travis-ci.org